# How to change an image in a window MFC application

Tags: c++, winapi

Let me start off by saying that I am very new to MFC applications, so please bear with me...

I would like to create a window with an image (lets say a green light). When necessary, I want the application to change the image (to a yellow or red light). I have code that will create the window and display the image (green light), but it will not update the image (when i == 15 or i == 50)

```
#include "resource.h"

using namespace std;

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

HBITMAP Light = NULL;

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT: 
        {   
            BITMAP bm;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;

            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, Light);

            GetObject(Light, sizeof(bm), &bm);

            BitBlt(hdc, 20, 180, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
            DeleteDC(hdcMem);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            Light = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
        }
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {

        }
        break; 
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        DeleteObject(Light);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;
    int eventCode;

    int i = 0;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCSTR)g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR)"Window Registration Failed!", (LPCSTR)"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        (LPCSTR)g_szClassName,
        (LPCSTR)"Test Picture",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 420, 280,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR)"Window Creation Failed!", (LPCSTR)"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);

        if (i == 15)
        {
            Light = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP3));
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        }
        else if (i == 50)
        {
            Light = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP2));
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        }
        i++;
    }

    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

I thought that I could do

```
Light = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP3));
UpdateWindow(hwnd);
```

to update the window picture, but I was wrong :( ...what could I use to change the image?

Comment: Did you set breakpoints and step through the code?  Did you check return codes from the API calls?

Comment: I'm not seeing any MFC here, just Windows API stuff. MFC *might* make this easier (CTimer, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call InvalidateRect to cause a repaint.  UpdateWindow doesn't do anything if the window's invalid region is empty.